# Ruby - jiraSOAP - Turn off OpenSSL cert verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, jira

How do I turn off certificate verification in a gem like jiraSOAP. the verification is inbuilt, but I really don't need that verification since the server & client are my properties. It should be doable to tweak the gem to stop this verification.

https://github.com/Marketcircle/jiraSOAP/blob/master/lib/jiraSOAP.rb

This cert verification error is stopping me moving on to my project. I have tried other solutions from forums, to upgrade my `/etc/ssl/cert`, adding `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` to my project. But none of them worked.

```
require 'jiraSOAP'
jira = JIRA::JIRAService.new "https://server/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl"
jira.login username, password


/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Comment: "*I really don't need that verification since the server & client are my properties*". The certificate verification (along with the host name verification) is there to make sure your client is indeed talking to the intended server. The fact that they're your property is irrelevant: you still want to make sure you're communicating with *your* server indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it modifying the Handsoap gem to ignore cert check only for my host.

File to modify in the gems path -

```
      handsoap-1.1.8/lib/handsoap/http/drivers/net_http_driver.rb
```

Modify after this new http client -

```
      http_client = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
```

Add this -

```
      #Added these new lines below 
      if url.host == "server" #ignore cert check only for this host
      http_client.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
      end
```

Comment: Again, don't ignore the certificate verification. That's what guarantees you that you're talking to the host you want. You could be talking to a host impersonating it otherwise.